# Having issues getting the output from subprocess.check_call()

Tags: python, linux, pdf, subprocess

I'm trying to get the output from this command: "hocr-pdf"
so when I run this command in my command line it works perfectly well and this is how I type it:

```
hocr-pdf . > converted.pdf
```

in order for this command to work I must have in the working directory 2 files with these extensions (jpeg ,hocr)
so when try to run this script containing this command It shows me this:

```
hocr-pdf: error: unrecognized arguments: gg
```

and this is my code:

```
from enter_filename import f2files
from f1fileOpen import f1file

from  findPDF import OCRized
import subprocess





a =f1file()

if not OCRized(a):
    p1=subprocess.check_call(["convert","-density","300",a,"-depth","8","converted.jpg"])
    print "Conversion to jpg was successful"
    p=subprocess.check_call(["tesseract","converted.jpg",'converted',"-l","eng","hocr"])
    print "tesseract done the job"
    p2=subprocess.check_call(["hocr-pdf",".>","gg"])
else:
    p=subprocess.check_call(["tesseract",'1.png','f1',"-l","eng"])
```

Comment: try: `(["hocr-pdf",".", ">" ,"gg"]`

Comment: I tried it already: it displays:  " > " unkown argument

Comment: Please look at the duplicate I just linked. When dealing with redirecting of stdout and stderr, you will have to handle it differently in Python. The preferred approach in Python3, is to use the "with open" context manager, which is explained in one of the answers in the link.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki What is the exact command you are using?

Comment: nope doesn't work here

Comment: @hamma Did you look at the answers in the link?

Comment: Yes i'm trying a solution : with open( file ) as

Comment: @hamma you should edit your question to show the potential solutions you have attempted and they results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use shell features , You should invoke the shell with the command:

```
p2=subprocess.check_call(["bash","-c","hocr-pdf .> gg"])
```

Comment: thank you ,it works